# How to add a data hover to a html anchor

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just wanted to add a data-hover to an HTML anchor tag something like this

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Pages</a>
```

I just want to see a drop down when I mouse hover on the link

Any help will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this it's working fine

$(".dropdown-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
```